# MySQL Master detail record on one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I basically would like to merge details from the details table in the row of the master.
So let's say I have a master table called **tbMaster** and a detail table called **tbDetail** with the following structures:

```
tbMaster
---------
ID Name
1  John
2  Sam
3  Bob
....


tbDetail
----------------------------------
ID IDmaster detailtype detailvalue
1  1        age        25
2  1        address    Longview Drive 48
3  1        wifename   Mary
4  2        age        31
5  2        address    MI, Courtesy Road 21
6  2        wifename   Rhonda
....
```

I did not build the DB so it's not my design...
But now I need to show a dataset where for each master record, I will have extra fields obtained from the detail table like bellow:

SQL result:

```
ID name age  wifename  address
--------------------------------------------
1  John 25   Mary      Longview Drive 48
2  Sam  31   Rhonda    MI, Courtesy Road 21
```

How can I achieve this?
I actually have more than one detail table for the same master with various data inside, so I will need multiple details from multiple detail tables.
I guess if I figure out how to do it for one detail table, I can solve the rest of the query.

So far I have no idea where to start...
Is this even possible with simple SQL?

Comment: are the distinct detailtypes fixed?

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them directly. the workarounds get ugly, fast. you'd be better off doing the column->row conversion in client-side code.

Comment: `SELECT M.ID,
       M.Name,
       MAX(IF(D.detailtype='age',detailValue,NULL)) as age,
       MAX(IF(D.detailtype='wifename',detailValue,NULL)) as wifename,
       MAX(IF(D.detailtype='address',detailValue,NULL)) as address
FROM tbMaster M
INNER JOIN tbDetail D
ON M.ID = D.IDMaster
GROUP BY M.ID,M.Name`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02a0b/1

Comment: The distinct detailtypes are FIXED. Each master record has the same type of details (same number of details and types of details)

Comment: Great stuff @Tin Tran make it an answer, since your code works. Thank you

Comment: glad it worked out for ya, i can't make an answer because it's marked as duplicate